# Grid in plt.loglog() plot for both axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, loglog

[result of the full code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCjib.png)
I try to get log scale for both axes and use code:

```
plt.subplot(4, 1, 1)
    plt.loglog(w, A_e)
    plt.loglog(w, A_l)
    plt.xlabel('ω, рад/c')
    plt.ylabel('A(ω), дБ')
    plt.grid(which='both', axis='both', ls="-")
```

but I get log scale only on x axe. How can I make it on both axes?

I tried to use smth like this

```
plt.yticks([1e-3, 1e-2, 1e-1, 1, 10, 100], ['$10^{-3}$', '$10^{-2}$', '$10^{-1}$', '1', '10', '100'])
```

but it didn't help

Comment: You do have a log scale on both axes. You only get tick marks (and therefore grid lines) on major ticks on the y axes -- i.e. on integer powers of 10, so you don't get the variable spacing of grid lines. But this does not mean you don't have a log scale. Because the range of your y-limits is large, it wouldn't look great to squash in all the minor ticks as well, so they are left off